# spring scheduler cron expression every 20 mins between 11 AM to 11 PM daily

Tags: spring, cron

I want spring scheduler job which will run every 20 mins between 11 AM to 11 PM

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution
It was simple. I just had to give hours as 11-23
0 0/20 11-23 * * *